# go to a specific line of a text file by shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have two text file. The structure of those two file is same. I have a while loop which reads from those two text file at the same time. But both of those two file , first 4 line is not needed. so what i need is, at the very starting of  my program the two head will jump to line number 4 of both of those files and then start to read through my while loop.
Here is my current code

```
while read compareFile1 <&3 && read compareFile2 <&4; do
echo $compareFile1
echo $compareFile2 
done 3<test1.txt 4<test2.txt
```

Here is my sample file ..

```
=== Predictions on test data ===

    inst#     actual  predicted error prediction (id)
        1 1:positive 1:positive       0.774 (10001996.txt)
        2 1:positive 2:negative   +   0.889 (10003432.txt)
        3 1:positive 1:positive       1 (10003865.txt)
        4 1:positive 1:positive       0.999 (10004065.txt)
        5 1:positive 1:positive       0.991 (10004266.txt)
        6 1:positive 1:positive       0.999 (10006157.txt)
        7 1:positive 1:positive       0.869 (10007003.txt)
        8 1:positive 2:negative   +   1 (10008447.txt)
        9 1:positive 1:positive       0.998 (10009702.txt)
       10 1:positive 1:positive       0.994 (10011072.txt)
```

How can i do this by bash? I am using mac. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `tail` utility. By default, it outputs the last 10 lines of a file, but it also has some quite useful parameters. To skip the first X lines, use `-n+X`.

Example:

```
 tail -n+5 myfile.txt
```

will output the whole file from the 5th line (skipping the first 4).

But in your case, you could simply increment a variable to start the processing on line 4. Example:

```
l=0 
while read compareFile1 <&3 && read compareFile2 <&4; do
  if [[ $l < 4 ]]; then 
     l=$((l+1)); 
  else
     # do your processing here
     echo $compareFile1
     echo $compareFile2 
  fi  
done 3<test1.txt 4<test2.txt
```

Comment: please see my edited question. I added my code and file.  " tail -n+5 myfile.txt "  command is returning the part of the file ..not shifting the pointer head (as far as i understood)

Comment: Thanks man, that's a very quick and easy solution. I am wondering, why i did not think about it

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative, it avoids reading both files in a shell loop:

```
nl File1.txt | paste - File2.txt | sed -n '5,$ p'
```

It produces in the first column the line number (via `nl`), then there is the content of first file, followed by the content of the second file. The `sed` command removes the first four lines.

Instead of `sed` you could plug in `awk` and access the fields from your files.

Depending on the files size this could be faster.

Answer (score -1):

To read in all but the first 4 lines of myfile:
    tail -n +4 myfile